# Prevent fold background color to override gutter

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Here's what my colorscheme looks like:

[image: colorscheme]

But when there are folds, it looks ugly like this:

[image: colorscheme with folding]

The fold background overrides the "gutter" color, but I would like the gutter to remain gray.

Is there any way to fix this? I have tried `hi Folded guibg=NONE` but it still overrides the gutter color.

Comment: try `:hi Folded guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE`

Comment: It doesn't change anything

Comment: I am afraid, then there is nothing more to do besides `:hi! link Folded SignColumn`

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm fearing. Doesn't look great either with the hi link.